# How to begin editing sites?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, domain-registration, nameserver

I'm new to creating web-sites and I have just registered a domain name here: from Europe Registry and started trial version of hosting from: ispserver.com.

I shall connect domain and hosting somehow and the only thing I've found at Europe Registry was this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPLNg.jpg is it the right menu, how do I find the host name of my hosting provider, IP address of what should I specify, why are there two groups of fields, are there any other steps required before editing the site? Maybe, there's already a guide somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting company that you picked appears to do both DNS hosting and Web hosting.  The registry that you chose appears to be able to do both domain registry and DNS hosting.  There should be two paths that you can take.  You can use either of the places to host your DNS.

### To use your hosting company for DNS

1. Log into your web host and set up your domain name on their website.  I can't give you specific help with this because I have never used the web host that you have chosen.
2. Log back into your registry and tell it what the DNS servers for your webhost using "Delegate to your nameservers".  The hosting company should tell you what its nameservers are.  Based on a Google search I did, the main one appears to be `ns1.ispvds.com`, but there should be at least two, and they should tell you this in the process of setting up your domain.
3. Put your site on your hosting company server.

### To use your registar to host your DNS

1. Log into your web host and set up your domain name on their website.
2. Find out from your web host what the IP address of the server that is hosting your website will be
3. Use the "Setup/Edit DNS Zone Records" on your registrar and enter that IP address as an A record.
4. Put your site on your hosting company server.

---

[Here is a guide that may help you through this process](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/5-fundamental-steps-to-deploying-a-website/)

Answer (score 0):

"how do I find the host name of my hosting provider, IP address of what should I specify"

All these details should be provided to you by the hosting provider.

To create and put your site online you'll need to do the following:

Choose a domain name and order a domain registration from any registrar that'll suit you by price (for example, Godaddy, Enom or Network Solutions). You can buy a domain with the hosting package, however it's best to contact a company that specializes in this field. Hosting companies also cooperate with these companies to buy domains for their clients and act as mediators between the client and the registrar company. Most clients think that if they buy a hosting package the domain will come for free. However, the hosting company already has the price of the domain added to the package.

Before you order a hosting, read some reviews on several analytical forums (for example, webhostinggeeks.com, webhostingtalk.com или webhostingw.com) or ask you friends who already own a website.

Copy site files using FTP with the help of such programs as FileZilla, SmartFTP, etc. or a standard hosting File manager. If you're using cPanel, you can get direct access to it in the File section. You can find it in the Sites and Domains section in Plesk if you're using a Windows based hosting.

If you don't have a site yet, create it using CMS (Content Management System), Joomla, Wordpress or Drupal. For installation, download CMS, copy it into site folder (httpdocs or public_html) and run install.php in your browser. The install link for Wordpress will look like this: http://domain.com/wp-admin/install.php или http://domain.com/folder/wp-admin/install.php” –if the installation was successful.

All modern hosting providers support almost all known CMS systems, therefore, you can always ask the tech support to help you with the installation.

Point your site to the hosting's DNS. You can do it yourself if you have access to the control panel.

Wait until the DNS servers update (the process may take from 2 to 72 hours depending on the domain area) and check your site online.